# GPG : Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input

Tags: python, gnupg

Here's as snippet I am using to encrypt a file.

```
import os, gnupg

def encrypt(key, src, dst):
    home = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "gnupg")
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(use_agent=True,homedir=home)
    with open(key, "rb") as f:
          keys = gpg.import_keys(f.read())
    with open(src, "rb") as f:  
         result = gpg.encrypt(f.read(), keys.fingerprints,output=dst)
         print result.stderr
    #      print result
    # if not result:
    #     raise RuntimeError(result.status)

encrypt('/Users/zone2/Desktop/Script/Playground/key.asc','/Users/zone2/Desktop/Script/Playground/sam.csv','/Users/zone2/Desktop/Script/Playground/res.csv')
```

This currently fails with `gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input`
Any help or resource to fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesn't make this at all clear but if you want to pass in a list of recipients like (keys.fingerprints is a list), you have to call gpg.encrypt(plaintext, *recipients, …).

If you get it wrong, python-gnupg will happily call gpg without any --recipient arguments, and it'll break.

`result = gpg.encrypt(f.read(), *keys.fingerprints,always_trust=True,output=dst)`
fixed this for me.